# JAVA Inheritance student, undergrad and gradstudent code

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, subclass, superclass

For a class project I was asked to create three codes. 
Student Class

1. First, the student class containing three Parameters.

   - Name(String)
   - TestScores( int array),
   - Grade(String).
2. An empty Constructor. sets the Name and Grade to empty Strings. The TestScores Array will be initialised with three zeros.
3. Another Constructor(String n, int[] tests, String g)- This will set the `name`, `testScores`, and `grade`.
4. Three methods:

   - `getName()` to return the `name`
   - `getGrade()` to return the `grade`
   - `setGrade()` to set `grade`
   - `getTestAverage()` to return the average of the test scores.
5. *This is where I am having difficulty* The method `computeGrade()`, which, if the average is greater than or equal to 65, the grade is a "Pass". Otherwise it is a "Fail".

The second class is called `UnderGrad`. This class is a subclass of Student.

1. We had to create an empty Constructor and another Constructor (`String n, int[] tests, String g`).
2. We were instructed to override the `computeGrade()` method so that an UnderGrad() student must get a 70 or higher to pass.

The third class is the `GradStudent` a subclass of Student.

1. We have to create 1 instance variable, `int MyGradID`, and an empty constructor, which calls super, and set the IDs to 0.
2. And another constructor `(String n, int[] tests, String g, int id)`- Remember to call the super constructor and set ID.
3. **Again where I am having challenges.** We had to write the method `getId()`, to return the ID number. Again we needed to override the `computeGrade()` method And, if the average is greater than or equal to 65, the grade is a "Pass". Otherwise it is a "Fail". But if the test average is higher than 90, the grade should be "Pass with distinction".

I have great difficulty with this task. I attached the `GradStudent` code. Can you find the errors please? I don't fully understand how to override the superclass private instance variables.

```
public class GradStudent extends Student {

    private int MyGradID;

    public void GradStudent() {
        super();
        MyGradID = 0;
    }

    public void GradStudent(String n, int[] tests, String g, int id) {
        super(n, tests, g);
        MyGradID = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return MyGradID;
    }

    @Override public void computeGrade() {
        if (testScores.getTestAverage() >= 65) {
            super.setGrade("Pass");
        } else if (testScores.getTestAverage() > 90) {
            grade = "Pass with distinction";
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Student class`. I'm not sure if I am referencing my super class correctly, so I am adding it. Hopefully you can explain it to me.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int[] testScores = new int[3];
    private String grade;

    public Student() {
        name = "";
        grade = "";
        testScores[0] = 0;
        testScores[1] = 0;
        testScores[2] = 0;
    }

    public Student(String n, int[] tests, String g) {
        name = n;
        testScores = tests;
        grade = g;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String newGrade) {
        grade = newGrade;
    }

    public int getTestAverage() {
        int average = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int testScore : testScores) {
            count++;
            average = average + testScore;
        }
        return average / testScores.length;
    }

    public void computeGrade() {
        grade = "Fail";
        if (this.getTestAverage() >= 65) {
            grade = "Pass";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your question its very hard to read.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with `getTestAverage()` in your `Student` class, but `count` variable serves no purpose. It is incremented and then never used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What jumps out at me is

```
    if(testScores.getTestAverage>=65)
```

Try changing that to

```
    if(testScores.getTestAverage()>=65)
```

Easy mistake to make. Hope this helps!
Edit - I see that twice.

Also, I don't *think* constructors should have a return type void (or any) though I could be wrong.

Comment: *Also, I don't think constructors should have a return type void (or any) though I could be wrong.* Correct, constructors need no return type. Proper implementation would be `public GradStudent(String n, int[] tests String g, int id)`

Comment: Thank you, yes that is very helpful. I keep getting the error    ./GradStudent.java:25: error: testScores has private access in Student 
if(testScores.getTestAverage()>=65) how can I reference testScores in gradStudent if it is private?

Comment: Woohoo! I helped. :)

Comment: As long as there is a public getter in the same class you should be able to use it even if the variable's private

Comment: @vmjiron for starters, `testScores` is of type `int[]` and `getTestAverage()` belongs to the `Student` class. I believe you want `super.getTestAverage()` instead of `testScores.getTestAverage()`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much. I actually see what is happening. Yes, it was supposed to be super.getTestAverage().

Comment: So um could you un-minus one me? It's my second answer ever I hate to start this way lol

Comment: Thx :) It gave me an achievement!

Answer (score 0):

This question simply wouldn't exist if you had an IDE (or, looked at the feedback from compile). I pasted the code into Eclipse and out popped a lot of problems.

Let's look at `GradStudent`.

```
public class GradStudent extends Student {

    private int MyGradID;

    // Constructors do not return anything.
    public GradStudent() {
        super();
        MyGradID = 0;
    }

    // Again, constructors do not return anything.
    public GradStudent(String n, int[] tests, String g, int id) {
        super(n, tests, g);
        MyGradID = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return MyGradID;
    }

    // Okay. Override annotation in place. Now, computeGrade() needs to get its data from someplace. Fortunately, we
    // have a method in Student to do that for us. That method is called 'getTestAverage()'. You do not need to
    // reference the array created in 'Student'.
    @Override public void computeGrade() {
        int testAverage = getTestAverage();

        if (testAverage >= 65) {    // Evaluate against that testAverage. There is no method (or parameter) associated
                                    // with an array that will compute its average.
            setGrade("Pass");
        } else if (testAverage > 90) {
            setGrade("Pass with distinction");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Student` class is just fine (though `count` in `getTestAverage()` is a pointless variable which doesn't do anything and an `int[]` is created with all values being initialised to 0).

Now I would question why the instructor would have told you to create a constructor to set the grade... when you don't actually know what the grade is... but whatever.

Where are you having trouble with the `computeGrade()` method in `Student`? It seems fine to me. The problem in `GradStudent` is fixed given the changes made above.

Comment: Thank you, but the fixes that you have pointed out are incorrect. The other answer helped me work through the process.    " _The issue I was having was how to apply the superclass methods. testScores is of type int[] and getTestAverage() belongs to the Student class. I believe you want super.getTestAverage() instead of testScores.getTestAverage() – _" -Calvin P. Thank you though.

Comment: In `computeGrade()` for `GradStudent`, `int testAverage = getTestAverage();` solves.